# Parsing multiple keyword value pairs in one line - mixed delimiters - Text::Balanced

Tags: perl

Have the the following file structure - see the **DATA** section:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Balanced qw(extract_bracketed);

my($ALL, $name, $pairs);
while(defined($name = <DATA>) && defined($pairs = <DATA>)) {
    $ALL->{$name} = parse_pairs($pairs);
}

sub parse_pairs {
    my $str = shift;

    my($extracted, $remainder) = extract_bracketed($str,'{}'); # how to?


}    
__DATA__
name1
key1 val1 key2 {val2a val2b} key3 val3
name2
key2 val2 key3 val3
name3
key1 {val1a val1b val1c} key2 {val2a val2b}
```

e.g. every odd line contain an unique "name", and every even line contain multiple "key value" pairs - space delimited.

- The key is always one word (\w+)
- the value can be:

  - one string (\S+), or
  - multiple space delimited strings, enclosed with brackets { }

Need get the above file into an perl structure, either:

```
$ALL => {
    name1 => {
        key1 => ["val1"],
        key2 => ["val2a", "val2b"],
        key3 => ["val3"]
    },
[.......]
```

or

```
$ALL => {
    name1 => {
        key1 => {
           val1 => undef,
        },
        key2 => {
           val2a => undef,
           val2b => undef,
        }
        key3 => {
           val3 => undef,
        }
    },
[.......]
```

This is *probably* a job for the Text::Ballanced, but havent any idea how to use it, because here are mixed values, some are only simple word and some are ballanced - bracket enclosed, and don't know how to *repeat* the extraction. ;(

Need some hints, how to write the `parse_pairs` sub in the above src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I have.  It's not using Text::Balanced, however.  It's using Regexp::Common:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Common;

my($ALL, $name, $pairs);
while(defined($name = <DATA>) && defined($pairs = <DATA>)) {
    chomp $name;
    chomp $pairs;
    $ALL->{$name} = parse_pairs($pairs);
}
use Data::Dump; dd $ALL;

sub parse_pairs {
    my $str = shift;

    my @key_values = $str =~ /
        (\w+)    # key
        \s*
        (\w+|$RE{balanced}{-parens=>'{}'}) # value
        \s*/xg;

    my $r;
    while (@key_values)
    {
        $key_values[1] =~ s/^\{//;
        $key_values[1] =~ s/\}$//;
        $r->{$key_values[0]} = [ split /\s+/, $key_values[1] ];
        splice @key_values, 0, 2;
    }
    $r;
}
__DATA__
name1
key1 val1 key2 {val2a val2b} key3 val3
name2
key2 val2 key3 val3
name3
key1 {val1a val1b val1c} key2 {val2a val2b}
```

This seems to produce the output you're looking for (option 1).

Comment: Thank you very much! Excactly what i want. Wonderful. ;) Now need somewhat understand it.. ;)

Comment: The regex scans the line for keys/values.  For values, it can either be \w+ (a "word") or something in braces (there's probably an easier way if nested braces aren't possible).  Once we have the list, odd items are keys and even are values.  If the value has braces on either end, remove them.  Split on spaces (if there were no braces, there's no space, split does nothing).  Assign to return hash. Splice off the two items, loop for next two.